# Asp.NET Serenity Multi Forms

Tags: asp.net, serenity-platform, serenity

In ASP.NET Serenity Framework:
I want to add Product and Order's form in CustomerDialog in different tabs, when we add new Customer we can save this and change the tabs and add new Product and save this.
the note is different save buttons for different tabs.
How can i do it?